# Comparing JavaScript objects

Tags: javascript

0
:
{a: "5", b: "gg", X: "dd", Y: "dd", Z: "dd"}
1
:
{X: "dd", Y: "dd", Z: "dd"}
2
:
{X: "df", Y: "dd", Z: "dd"}

I want to compare these objects with each other so that i can not add repeated object in an array.

Comment: So what would your array contain, when checking the above values?

Comment: please elaborate on the reqs. How are you comparing these objects? Based on each property inside one object exactly matching to the other object (or would it matter to have extra properties in one than the other)? And how are the objects added to the array?

Comment: if you want to check while adding object on key than try `angular.extend()` or want to match 2 objects then use `angular.equals()`

Comment: What does this have to do with AngularJS or Angular?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question with given information, there can be 2 possible scenarios.

1. if you want to add one object to another object (merge) based on key than it can be done with [angular.extend](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend) and the same key will be overwritten by later object keys

   ```
    let inp1 = {a: "aa", b: "bb", X: "xx", Y: "yy", Z: "zz"};
    let inp2 = {X: "xxx", Y: "yyy", Z: "zzz", W: "www"};
    let inp3 = {X: "x3", Y: "y3", Z: "z3"};

    angular.extend(inp1, inp2);
    console.log("inp1", inp1);
    // print {"a": "aa", "b": "bb", "X": "xxx","Y": "yyy","Z": "zzz","W": "www"}
   ```
2. if you simply want to compare two objects before adding into another object or (push into array) then you can do it with [angular.equals](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.equals)

   ```
   anguar.equals(inp2,inp3) // return false
   ```